# Sort a Hashmap by Value in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I've got a HashMap that I need sorting by value and I'm trying to keep it concise, so I'm using Java 8. However various methods aren't working and I'm unsure why. I've tried this:

```
followLikeCount.values()
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which throws this compile time exception:

```
Main.java:65: error: no suitable method found for sorted(Comparator<Entry<Object,V#1>>)
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
```

I can't see why there is a mismatch from observation. I've also tried using the comparator:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> byValue =
          Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue();
```

Which yields a similar error. Please could you advise why the comparators aren't valid?

Comment: Does `values()` return the `Entry` with key/value pairs, or just the values?

Comment: Ah true, just the values, but I can't turn the HashMap followLikeCount into a stream directly. Is a different method altogether required?

Comment: Try `entrySet()`.  You can stream the set.

Comment: Maps have also a method `entrySet()` that returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`

Comment: Ah, perfect. So the comparator compile-time error was due to expecting a comparator for just the value part. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to use a `Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>` on `List<Integer>` returned by `values()`

```
followLikeCount.values()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

You need to use this comparator on a `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>` which can be returned by `entrySet()` :

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = followLikeCount.entrySet()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If you want to get only the values, sorted, you can change the `Comparator` and get back a `List<Integer>` :

```
List<Integer> list = followLikeCount.values()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If you only want to get the sorted (`Comparable`) values, you can even do with a comparator, `followLikeCount.values() .stream() .sorted() .collect(Collectors.toList());`. Or without Streams: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(followLikeCount.values()); list.sort(null);`